# descargar un tag en especifico de un repositorio git

Tags: git

Realice una descarga al servidor con el siguiente comando

```
git clone --branch tag_1 mi_url
```

pero me solicitaron que instalara el `tag_2`, verifique los tag que se encuentran ejecutando el comando

```
git tag -l
```

me salio el listado de tag y si estaba, mi pregunta es como hago un **`git pull`** que solo descargue la version `tag_2`, y si es asi conocen algun comando donde se puede visualizar que `tag` esta instalado en el repositorio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para descargar un **`tag`** en especifico se debe ejecutar la siguiente linea

```
 git checkout tags/nombre_del_tag
```

en mi caso

```
 git checkout tags/tag_2
```

si por alguna razon quieres descargar un **`tag`** de un **`branch`** en particular se debe ejecutar el siguiente comando

```
git checkout tags/nombre_tag -b branch
```

en mi caso seria de esta forma

```
git checkout tags/tag_2 -b master
```