# ¿Para qué se usan los tags en Git?

Tags: git

Se que los **tags** existen, pero nunca los he usado y aun no me he encontrado con nadie que los use, **¿para qué se usan?**

Por lo que pone en la [documentación de Git](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Fundamentos-de-Git-Creando-etiquetas), es una forma de crear un **histórico de mensajes**, paralelo al de los commits para marcar sólo los cambios más importantes, ¿es sólo eso? ¿tiene más usos?

Comment: Algo a tener en cuenta es ejecutar la instrucción "git push origin --tags" para que los tags creados los deje reflejados en el repositorio remoto con el fin de que el resto del equipo los tenga accesibles.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Literalmente *tag* significa *etiqueta*.

Cada vez que haces un commit, se crea un identificador único del tipo `0dc20efa9ec36cefd67dcb832d9b01b7531c3a33`, pero aunque pongas un comentario diciendo *"Este commit es la versión en producción del día D"*, no es algo fácil de consultar, así que puedes crear una etiqueta que te ayude a encontrarlo o a volver a él rápidamente. Si creaste una etiqueta en ese momento del tipo *v1.0.0*, siempre podrás hacer un `git checkout v1.0.0` y obtendrás el código tal cual estaba.

Cuando te mueves a un *tag* es como moverse a una rama, pero en modo *detached*: no puedes modificar el código y hacer un commit a menos que crees una rama porque lo que tienes es un *snapshot*, una instantánea del código en un momento dado.

Además, los *commits* suelen tener como comentario qué se cambió en el código: una nueva funcionalidad, un parche a un fallo, un cambio estético... etc. Una etiqueta puede tener como comentario información sobre el despliegue, la lista de cambios desde la versión anterior... además de que la propia etiqueta ya puede darte una idea (si usas [semver](https://semver.org/lang/es/)) de los cambios que puede haber y el nivel de retrocompatibilidad.

Answer (score 8):

Adicionalmente a la respuesta de Pablo, que está impecable, cabe señalar que cuando públicas una librería en un registro de paquetes (npmjs en el caso de node, packagist es el caso de PHP) no correspondería que la gente que usa tu librería se traiga la rama #master cada vez que instala.

Por el contrario, tu librería tendrá un manifiesto (package.json para node, composer.json para PHP) que declara explícitamente la versión. Y esa versión está asociada a un tag del repositorio.

Cuando alguien instala tu librería puede pedir una versión específica (e.g. 0.9.2) y ésta se asocia a un tag, porque la idea es que si pides una versión específica el código que recibes sea siempre el mismo.

Los registros de paquetes suelen tener en caché las versiones de tu librería, de modo que cuando alguien l instala no tiene que pegarle a GitHub (que limita el ancho de banda en ese aspecto). Este caché permite a los registros mantener un abanico limitado de versiones, lo cual no sería practicable si tuvieran que cachear cada commit que haces.

Como efecto secundario, un tag publicado de esa manera te permite seguir modificando la rama máster sin preocuparte de dañar algo que estaba funcionando la última vez que lo viste. Esto es: si tu flujo de deploy de una aplicación deploya en producción no una rama sino un tag,  no vas a dañar el ambiente productivo añadiendo código a las ramas.

Vale la pena señalar que los tags existen en una jerarquía separada que las branches. Las branches están pensadas para generar nuevos features o parches y eventualmente volver a integrarse con máster. Un tag no está pensado para interactuar desde ni hacia otros tags ni ramas. Por lo mismo, puedes tener un millón de tags y el manejo de tu repo no aumenta en dificultad. Si manejas dos docenas de branches, en cambio, se vuelve inmanejable.

Comment: Muy interesante, ya sabía yo que había más de lo que parecía en la doc.

Answer (score 5):

Sirven para dejar un registro, una marca de una versión en concreto. Se hacen cuando publicas una versión (v0.1, v1.0, v2.2, etc.) de modo que puedas volver a dicha versión por si tuvieras que probar alguna funcionalidad o error que suceda en esa versión

Answer (score 2):

Tag es aplicada como metodologia de trabajo de GitFlow, la idea es tener las siguientes ramas

- Master:  rama principal
- HotFix : rama para arreglar los problemas en el servidor
- Develop : rama creada para el desarrollo
- Caracteristica: donde va el nombre de la caracteristica nueva que agregas ejemplo(orden_compra)

Cuando tienes un grupo de desarrolladores todos trabajan en distintas caracteristicas, debes entregar todo lo desarrollado al cliente (esto se conoce como release o liberacion) , una vez unificado las caracteristicas en develop y pasan las pruebas se apuntan a la rama master generando un nuevo tag.

---

Los tags son mas comunes de los que tu crees si trabajas en JavaScript notaras en el `package.json` existe algo como [@angular/cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases):

```
"@angular/cli": "v7.1.0",
```

que significa , traeme el repositorio en "`angular/cli`" cuyo tag sea "`v7.1.0`"

Si deseas saber como descargar un tag te invito a leer [Descargar un tag en espefico de un repositorio git](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86445/descargar-un-tag-en-especifico-de-un-repositorio-git)

Comment: ojo, el namespace del paquete no necesariamente implica un mapeo en github. Yo podría publicar mi repo [HuasoFoundries/systemjs-riot](https://github.com/HuasoFoundries/systemjs-riot) en npm como `@amenadiel/plugin_para_riot`, lo que importa es referenciar el repo en el `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Para congelar versiones finales del código, por ejemplo si tienes liberada la versión 1.0 del mismo puedes generarle un tag y los usuarios descarguen dicha versión.

En caso de encontrar un bug en el código del tag, se debe crear un nuevo branch que lo corrija, posteriormente se libere y el ciclo de los tags se repetiría.